# Blueimp SELECT only specific rows

Tags: php, mysql

this is what I'm struggingling with: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

I came across [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741899/blueimp-choose-only-some-rows-with-select-where-it-doesn-t-work) which is simarlar to my problem:

I have some products where you should be able to associate more than one image.

I have 3 tables

#### products ------------------  img_connecter ------------------- images

```
p_id  p_name             fk_p_id    fk_i_id               i_id  i_name  

1     Car                1          1                     1     car_1.jpg
2     Bus                1          2                     2     car_2.jpg
3     Truck              2          3                     3     bus_1.jpg
```

.

This is the code from the UploaderHandler.php file:

```
protected function get_file_objects($iteration_method = 'get_file_object') {
    $upload_dir = $this->get_upload_path();
    if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) {
        return array();
    }
    return array_values(array_filter(array_map(
        array($this, $iteration_method),
        scandir($upload_dir)
    )));
}
```

The scandir function is showing all the images in the folder so i was trying to change it to:

```
protected function get_file_objects() {

    $files = $this->query(" SELECT i_name FROM images i
                            LEFT JOIN img_connector c ON (c.fk_i_id = i.i_id)
                            LEFT JOIN products p ON (c.fk_p_id = p.p_id)
                            WHERE p_id = 1");
    $files_array=array();
    while($row = $files->fetch()){
        array_push($files_array, $row['i_name']);
    }

    return array_values( array_filter( array_map(
        array($this, 'get_file_object'),
        $files_array
    ) ) );
}
```

The query where it says "WHERE `p_id` = 1"

1 is going to be a $_GET[] variable. For now I'm just giving it a static number.

I cant figure out why it dosent show the images that the query is pointing too ??

Am I missing something ?

Comment: it should show all the three images because in the `img_connector` table, p_id has entries for all i_id

Comment: I see your point, i only added 3 rows of every table. I edited the "img_connecter"-table so it now should only show 2 images, but it still shows all the images

Comment: the columns name should be i_id and i_name. I just wrote it freehand because there is alot of others columns which isnt necessary to show.

Answer (score 0):

You are only selecting columns `id` and `name` (which don't seem to be mentioned in your DB schema above) but then you're referring to a row called `i_name` in your result set. [The query you're looking for is this one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14c54/1):

```
$files = $this->query("SELECT i_name FROM images i
    LEFT JOIN img_connector c ON (c.fk_i_id = i.i_id)
    LEFT JOIN products p ON (c.fk_p_id = p.p_id)
    WHERE p_id = 1
");
```

So, next you're (very verbosely) sticking them into an array. Assuming you took my advice and went with PDO for database access, doesn't hurt to grab all the filenames at once:

```
$files_array = $files->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Then you're passing every instance of the array through `$this->get_file_object()`, removing any empty ones, and returning the remaining values.

```
return array_values(
    array_filter(
        array_map([$this, 'get_file_object'], $files_array)
    )
 );
```

So the only thing left to check is what `get_file_object` is doing. The only instance under which it will return false is if the file doesn't exist in the upload directory. So, ensure the file is where it should be.

All this presupposes that you actually have a valid database connection; doing a `var_dump($files_array)` should tell you that pretty quickly.

Comment: the columns name should be i_id and i_name. I just wrote it freehand because there is alot of others columns which isnt necessary to show.

Comment: Ok, you shouldn't do that. Regardless, my answer's the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answers @miken32, i edited the code so it now looks like this, but it's still not showing anything.